# how to solve this error when i using ngx-translate?

Tags: json, html, typescript, ionic3, angular5

[image]

I have to solve this error, i am using ngx-translate in ionic 3 app to change the language.

Comment: The error says that json has wrong format. Send it please or check it by yourself.

Comment: Please do not post images of errors/code but include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is a issue with your `de.json` file. You can use something like [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to see what is wrong with the json file, alternatively post it here and someone can look through it.

Comment: thanks friend, but https://jsonlint.com/ have give valid json in results. please share some another solution.